# How to floor/ceil number to get this format using php?

Tags: php, floor, ceil

How to floor/ceil number to get this format using php ?

I want to get like this result

```
inpput====> output
.....
3.0 =======> 3.0
3.1 =======> 3.0
3.2 =======> 3.0
3.3 =======> 3.0
3.4 =======> 3.0
3.5 =======> 4.0
3.6 =======> 4.0
3.7 =======> 4.0
3.8 =======> 4.0
3.9 =======> 4.0
```

...................................................................

So, i use this code

```
$x = floor($input);
```

But i get this result

```
inpput====> output
.....
3.0 =======> 3.0
3.1 =======> 3.0
3.2 =======> 3.0
3.3 =======> 3.0
3.4 =======> 3.0
3.5 =======> 3.0
3.6 =======> 3.0
3.7 =======> 3.0
3.8 =======> 3.0
3.9 =======> 3.0
```

...................................................................

Then i use this code

```
$x = ceil($input);
```

But i get this result

```
inpput====> output
.....
3.0 =======> 3.0
3.1 =======> 4.0
3.2 =======> 4.0
3.3 =======> 4.0
3.4 =======> 4.0
3.5 =======> 4.0
3.6 =======> 4.0
3.7 =======> 4.0
3.8 =======> 4.0
3.9 =======> 4.0
```

How can i do for get thisa result ?

```
inpput====> output
.....
3.0 =======> 3.0
3.1 =======> 3.0
3.2 =======> 3.0
3.3 =======> 3.0
3.4 =======> 3.0
3.5 =======> 4.0
3.6 =======> 4.0
3.7 =======> 4.0
3.8 =======> 4.0
3.9 =======> 4.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use round function. ex,

```
$x = round ($input);
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Answer (score 1):

Use the [round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function instead, you then have access to the rounding modes.

```
<?php

foreach(range(3, 4, 0.1) as $i) {
   echo $i.' =======> '.number_format(round($i, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP), 1).PHP_EOL; 
}

/*
3   =======> 3.0
3.1 =======> 3.0
3.2 =======> 3.0
3.3 =======> 3.0
3.4 =======> 3.0
3.5 =======> 4.0
3.6 =======> 4.0
3.7 =======> 4.0
3.8 =======> 4.0
3.9 =======> 4.0
4   =======> 4.0
*/
```